# controller action returning View(tuple) asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller

Is there a way for the controller to pass a tuple as a model to the View?

Something like this:

```
return View(Tuple<LandingPage, Models.FilterModel>(landingPage, filter));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to instantiate the Tuple:

```
return View(new Tuple<LandingPage, Models.FilterModel>(landingPage, filter));
```

Although you're probably better off creating a composite view model type which contains properties for the landing page and the filter model.

Comment: Or create a view model which contains a tuple